# Unescape unicode characters using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, unicode, escaping

I am using an API which encodes some part of the content using JavaScript. That content is visible in the browser, but while I access it using `curl` in PHP I get plain JavaScript code as there is no JS engine on server. I would like to decode/unescape Unicode characters in PHP, as JavaScript does. Is that possible?

Please find a snippet of plain JavaScript I get as a response below:

```js
eval(unescape("document.write('%u0039%u0032%u0039%u0032%u0034')"));
```

The snippet code should return 92924

Comment: That is not "encoded" content, it is an escaped unicode notation.

Comment: Any solutions to that?

Comment: I'd say that curl doesn't contain JS engine, so Javascript is not launched. So instead of JS output you receive JS code

Comment: I completely understand that, but I would need to "execute" it some how, or simulate similar behaviour. I can parse out only unicode escaped content and unescape it, but I don't know how to unescape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution to that problem.

I am now parsing out the content string and then use json_decode function to unescape Unicode characters, but first %u has to be replaced with \u. Here is my code:

```
$string = "%u0039%u0032%u0039%u0032%u0034";
$unescaped = str_replace("%u","\u", $string);
echo json_decode('"'.$unescaped .'"');
```

This code would output: `92924`